# New Mailing Cannot "Review and Schedule"

Tags: mailing

CiviCRM 4.7.23, Drupal 7.39
I can fill the first page of a new mailing ("Define Mailing") but the "Next" button and the "Review and Schedule" tab are unresponsive. The mailing is listed under Draft and Unscheduled Mailings.

I've had the trouble before and was able to change a setting the civicrm_mailing table, but have forgotten what I did and cannot make the edits necessary to trigger the "Next" button.

I have searched similar questions, but could not find the same issue. I apologize if this is a duplicate request for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error got it to work by modifying record in table: civicrm_mailing
1) Set Is_Completed to 1 and
2) Approval_Status_ID to 1